# Transparency for PNG textures in OpenGL 1.0 Androi

Tags: android, opengl-es

A few years ago I was programming OpenGL 1.0 ES for Android and was able to get textures with transparency.

I am working on a 2D layer that is going to have square sprites (made up up of 2 triangles) but I need transparency.

When I try to include the code that I thought was suppose to do this, I am getting OpenGL errors.

```
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_ALPHA_TEST);
        gl.glAlphaFunc(GL10.GL_GREATER,0.0f);
```

Here is the full drawFrame(GL10 gl) function...

```
    public void drawFrame(GL10 gl)
    {
        super.drawFrame(gl);

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
        gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);


        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_ALPHA_TEST);
        gl.glAlphaFunc(GL10.GL_GREATER,0.0f);

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2,GL10.GL_FLOAT,0, textureBuffer);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,textureID);



        //Prep the Vertices
        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);        //Set the CULL direction
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);     //Enable culling
        gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);        //Set which side to CULL

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glColor4f(1f,1f,1f,0f);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);


        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES,0,vertexBuffer.capacity()/3);


        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_ALPHA_TEST);
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    }
```

And here is the function I use to load the image

```
public void LoadTexture(int resourceId, Context context, GL10 gl)
    {
        int[] textures = new int[1];

        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inScaled = false;

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),resourceId, opts);


        gl.glGenTextures(1,textures,0);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,textures[0]);

        textureID = textures[0];

        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,0, bm, 0);
        bm.recycle();
    }
```

Comment: *" I am getting OpenGL errors."* - What errors do you get? Why do you enable alpha test **and** [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending)? When blending?

Comment: In general I'd recommend moving away from OpenGL ES 1.x for new projects. It's an old API is much less efficient than OpenGL ES 2.x or  3.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL ES 1.x distinguishes between the Common and Common-Lite profile. See [OpenGL ES 1.0.02 Specification - Appendix A](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/1.0/opengles_spec_1_0.pdf#page=55&zoom=100,120,126).
While Alpha-Test is supported in Common profile it is not in Common-Lite profile. See [OpenGL ES 1.0.02 Specification - 4.1 Per-Fragment Operations](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/1.0/opengles_spec_1_0.pdf#page=26&zoom=100,72,401)

If you want to draw partially transparent textures, then it is sufficient to use [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending). You do not need an Alpha-Test at all.